# How can I kill System Tray icon application?

Tags: nsis

I need to stop and kill a system tray icon application in NSIS scriptes ?

```
KillProcDLL::KillProc "xyz.exe"
KillProcDLL::KillProc "xyz"
nsisDDE::Execute "xyz-{D30034F8-AB97-419F-B3B6-FA5BB8CD926F}" "[Quit]"
nsisDDE::Execute "xyz" "[Quit]"
nsisDDE::Execute "D30034F8-AB97-419F-B3B6-FA5BB8CD926F" "[Quit]"
```

all above didn't works ?

Comment: How is the fact that it is a "tray" application relevant? We also need to know which application you want to close. And is it a 64-bit application? Where did you get that GUID from?

Comment: it's a 64 bit C# application using NotifyIcon onject, D30034F8-AB97-419F-B3B6-FA5BB8CD926F is assembly guid and 02639d71-0935-35e8-9d1b-9dd1a2a34627 is a mutex id

Comment: DDE does not usually use GUIDs. Did you write this C# application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KillProcDLL in 32-bit NSIS cannot kill a 64-bit process, you must use [KillProcWMI](https://web.archive.org/web/20151225151345/http://www.chironexsoftware.com/downloads/KillProcWMI.zip).

Killing a process is not ideal, it is better to use the [LockedList plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/LockedList_plug-in) or use `FindWindow` + `SendMessage $window ${WM_CLOSE} 0 0` to gently close the application.

`FindWindow` can only be used if the window has a unique window class. Use Spy++ (Visual Studio), [WinSpy++](https://www.catch22.net/software/winspy) or [WinSpyEx](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=28220) to find the window class.